# Remove content from input

Tags: dynamic, removechild

can someone help me out with this script. I am trying to do a Formular for submit a recipe. 
I want to do a dynamic ingredient formular, where i can add and remove ingredients.

Unfortunately it doesn´t work as I want. My removing function is always removing the first ingredient. How can I remove the the igredient I want to.

Here is my code so far:

```js
function copy(objButton)
{
if(objButton.parentNode)
    {
    hinzufg=objButton.parentNode.cloneNode(true);
    objButton.form.appendChild(hinzufg);
    for(j=0;j<objButton.form.lastChild.childNodes.length;++j)
        {
        if(objButton.form.lastChild.childNodes[j].type=='text')
            {
            objButton.form.lastChild.childNodes[j].value='';
            break;
            }
        }
  
    }
}
 
 function remove(objButton)
 {
  var entf = document.getElementById('ingredients');
  entf.parentNode.removeChild(entf);
    }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Recipe</title>

</head>

<form action="">

<h2>Recipes</h2>
  <strong>Name</strong> <br />
  <input type="text" size="50" > <br /><br />
  <strong>Ingredients</strong> <br />
  
<div id="ingredients">
 <input type="text" id="AmountIngredients" name="zutatMenge1[]"> ... 
    <input type ="text" id="zutat" name="firstIngredient[]">  
 <input type="button" value="+" onclick="copy(this)">
 <input type="button" value="X" onclick="remove(this)">
 
 </div>
 
</form>


<body>
</body>
</html>
```